# honeycomb emulator reversed screen in portrait

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, screen-orientation

I just tested an app developed for Android 2 on the 3.2 emulator. The app supports only portrait mode, thus in default landscape mode of the emulator it's rotated by 90° (as on Android 2).
If however I rotate the emulator to portrait mode, the screen is shown reversed by 180°. That means, what should be on top is on the bottom of the screen and the other way round. It's not only the app, but also the Android status bar.
If I exit (background) the app, the issue disappears.
I've tested the app on several Phones and emulators, this never happened with Android 2. Can't test on a real Honeycomb device yet.

Comment: I've just got this problem also, its a very similar situation - Android 2 running on a 3.0 emulator. My app is upside down.

Answer (score 8):

what version of android 2 are you developing, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.1 or 2.3.3.

If it's 2.3.1 and higher then open your androidmanifest file. In the application tab select an activity. Then scroll down to **screen orientation** and select **sensorPortait** in the drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: is this the answer your looking for?

Answer (score 3):

was fixed by changing the properties of **config.ini** in

```
%SYSTEM_DRIVE%\Users\%USER_NAME%\.android\avd\YOUR_AVD_NAME_HERE
```

form

```
skin.path=1280x720
```

to

```
skin.path=720x1280
```

hope that'd help you

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate emulator screen by pressing 7 or 9 on numpad (windows)

Comment: Yes, but that only rotates 90 and back, not 180