# Android emulator upside down in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-x86

I'm using Eclipse to develop Android apps, using the emulator (with an image of Intel x86 for the Google API in 4.1.2) and the phone is upside down and "inside in", like this:

[image]

Any idea about why and how to fix it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rotating the emulator by

> Ctrl + F12

if the characters are still inverted then disable GPU emulation in avd settings

Comment: not working. CTRL + F12 only works to set it to landscape and back to portrait, but it doesn't turn it 180 degrees. And deactivating GPU emulation doesn't work either; actually it makes it worse since it gets so slow that it becomes unusable

Comment: sorry you're right, disabling GPU emulation works, but then the emulator is really unusable

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to what worked for me (4.0.3 through 4.2.2).

[honeycomb emulator reversed screen in portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027185/honeycomb-emulator-reversed-screen-in-portrait)

Here's the important part

"sroll down to screen orientation and select sensorPortait in the drop-down menu".

Note: you'll probably need to do this for each activity if you're launching them in a stack. You can just copy/paste in the manifest file after you've done the first one.

Answer (score 1):

was fixed by changing the properties of config.ini in

%SYSTEM_DRIVE%\Users\%USER_NAME%.android\avd\YOUR_AVD_NAME_HERE

from

skin.path=1280x720

to

skin.path=720x1280

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, too.

But after I installed the Android SDK Tools 21.1 rc (in Preview Channel), the emulator with host GPU enabled works great now.

Just launch Android SDK Manager and enable the preview channel in the settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same for me with WXGA. Here's the fix:
Set the device to portrait. 
Change the auto rotate in system setting to OFF.
App will now run right side up.